# java adding jpanels from other classes

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

I am developing a game in java and I am trying to load different levels from different class files. Each level class file is a jpanel. The idea was that when level1 is done it loads a method that removes the jpanel level1 and adds the jpanel level2. But when I am trying to load level2 from level1 I get a java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread. Error

I have 3 class files:

- main: loads the jframe and the method that adds jpanels
- level1: loads level1 and then loads level2 through the method in main
- level2: loads level2

this is the method in the main class:

```
public static void levelChanger(int currentMap){
    map1 map1 = new map1(null);
    map2 map2 = new map2(null);

    if(currentMap == 1){
        frame.add(map1);
        frame.validate();
    }else if(currentMap == 2){
        frame.remove(map1);
        frame.add(map2);
        frame.validate();
    }
}
```

And this is how i call it from level1:

```
mainScreen.levelChanger(2);
```

Hope I provided enough information. Thanks!

---

This is the entire main class:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class mainScreen{

    static JFrame frame = new JFrame("Tile System");

    //Key variables
    public static int keyUp = KeyEvent.VK_UP;
    public static int keyDown = KeyEvent.VK_DOWN;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        levelChanger(1);
        frame.setSize ( 800, 600 );
        frame.setResizable ( false );
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo ( null );
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation ( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
        frame.setVisible ( true );
        frame.setBackground(new Color(135, 206, 250));//RGB color code
        frame.setFocusable(true);

        new map1(null);
    }
    public static void exit(){
        WindowEvent wev = new WindowEvent(frame, WindowEvent.WINDOW_CLOSING);
        Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemEventQueue().postEvent(wev);
    }

    public static void levelChanger(int currentMap){
        public static map1 map1 = new map1(null);
            public static map2 map2 = new map2(null);
        if(currentMap == 1){
            frame.add(map1);
            frame.validate();
        }else if(currentMap == 2){
            frame.remove(map1);
            frame.add(map2);
            frame.validate();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Class names should start with an uppercase letter :) "map1 map1 = new map1()" kinda hurts my eyes.

Comment: can you add more implementation code, like the `mainScreen` class. According to your code, the `frame` is a static `JFrame` variable?

Comment: I think you are overusing `static` here. The `frame` could be the instance variable of `mainscreen`, the methods `exit` and `levelchanger` could be the `public` methods. Then in the `main` method, you just use `new mainscreen()`.

Answer (score 3):

First, the `OutOfMemoryError` doesn't really have anything with this code, probably `map1` and `map2` are allocating lots of memory, maybe this answer will help you relasing some of that memory.

1. Each time you are calling `levelChanger` you are allocating a new `map1` and `map2` object. Even though you will only use *one* of these objects
2. You are not removing the same `map1` object when changing to level 2.
3. (You could let `levelChanger` take a `map` parameter instead)

---

An improved `levelChanger` method could look like this:

```
// allocate maps once
static map1 map1 = new map1(null);
static map2 map2 = new map2(null);

public static void levelChanger(int currentMap){

    if (currentMap == 1){
        frame.add(map1);
        frame.validate();
    } else if (currentMap == 2) {
        frame.remove(map1);
        frame.add(map2);
        frame.validate();
    }
}
```

---

A better way would be create an interface `Map` and let `map1` and `map2` implement `Map`, also creating an own panel (`mapPanel`) for the map. Something like this:

```
public static void levelChanger(Map map){
    mapPanel.removeAll();
    mapPanel.add(map);
}
```

Comment: I tried with the improved levelchanger but now I am getting a java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError

Comment: Then you are getting an exception when initializing the `map1` and `map2`, check the wrapped exception and try to fix that problem (probably you are using somthing uninitialized).

Comment: something weird happened. I added a try block around the if statement in the level changer and now it works! map2 is now being loaded from map1.. Any explanation for this?

Comment: Are you ignoring the exception? If so, print the stack trace and debug why.

Comment: The `ExceptionInInitializeError` is thrown on initializing static variables. Perhaps the `new map1(null)` and `new map2(null)` have some problem. One more thing, why you pass `null` to the constructor?

Answer (score 0):

I can't be sure with the code you provide but your error is an OutOfMemoryError, did you increase the default java memory ? Try `-Xms512m  -Xmx1024m` command line options (or put in there whatever memory size you want).

Comment: No I have not increased the memory. Could you please tell me how to do that?